# Blogelator gem doesn't install properly/File to import not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, blog-engine

I'm trying to add Blogelator to my RoR application, but it's not installing properly. Whenever I run

```
rails g blogelator:install
```

it gets stuck on blogelator:install:migrations

```
 identical  app/controllers/blogelator/posts_controller.rb
   identical  app/assets/javascripts/blog.js
       exist  app/assets/javascripts/blog
   identical  app/assets/javascripts/blog/components/.gitkeep
   identical  app/assets/javascripts/blog/components/link.js
   identical  app/assets/javascripts/blog/layout/.gitkeep
   identical  app/assets/javascripts/blog/layout/progress_bar.js
   identical  app/assets/javascripts/blog/views/.gitkeep
   identical  app/views/layouts/blog.html.erb
       exist  app/views/layouts/blog
   identical  app/views/layouts/blog/_footer.html.erb
   identical  app/views/layouts/blog/_header.html.erb
   identical  app/assets/stylesheets/blog.scss
       exist  app/assets/stylesheets/blog
   identical  app/assets/stylesheets/blog/.gitkeep
   identical  app/assets/stylesheets/blog/components/.gitkeep
   identical  app/assets/stylesheets/blog/components/button.scss
   identical  app/assets/stylesheets/blog/components/headings.scss
   identical  app/assets/stylesheets/blog/components/link.scss
   identical  app/assets/stylesheets/blog/components/lists.scss
   identical  app/assets/stylesheets/blog/components/table.scss
   identical  app/assets/stylesheets/blog/layout/body.scss
   identical  app/assets/stylesheets/blog/layout/flash_messages.scss
   identical  app/assets/stylesheets/blog/layout/footer.scss
   identical  app/assets/stylesheets/blog/layout/header.scss
   identical  app/assets/stylesheets/blog/layout/progress_bar.scss
   identical  app/assets/stylesheets/blog/variables.scss
   identical  app/assets/stylesheets/blog/views/blogelator/authors/_author.scss
   identical  app/assets/stylesheets/blog/views/blogelator/posts/_post.scss
   identical  app/assets/stylesheets/blog/views/blogelator/posts/index.scss
   identical  app/assets/stylesheets/blog/views/blogelator/posts/show.scss
       exist  app/views/blogelator
   identical  app/views/blogelator/authors/_author.html.erb
   identical  app/views/blogelator/kaminari/_paginator.html.erb
   identical  app/views/blogelator/posts/_meta.html.erb
   identical  app/views/blogelator/posts/_post.html.erb
   identical  app/views/blogelator/posts/index.html.erb
   identical  app/views/blogelator/posts/show.html.erb
   identical  app/views/blogelator/tags/_tag.html.erb
        rake  blogelator:install:migrations
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'blogelator:install:migrations' (see --tasks)
```

I was able to figure out from digging around that the error was from blogelator now needing to be written as blogelator_engine in the last rake. I can run

```
rake blogelator_engine:install:migrations
```

and it works fine, but I don't know what else is missing that's not being run after the failed rake.

I tried to figure out a way to skip the one command during the install, but couldn't. The error that I'm getting when I run the application on localhost:3000 is

> File to import not found or unreadable: codelation.
>   Load paths:
>    /Users/adrian/Desktop/iotiportal/ioti-portal/app/assets/images
>    /Users/adrian/Desktop/iotiportal/ioti-portal/app/assets/javascripts
>    /Users/adrian/Desktop/iotiportal/ioti-portal/app/assets/stylesheets
>    /Users/adrian/Desktop/iotiportal/ioti-portal/vendor/assets/javascripts
>    /Users/adrian/Desktop/iotiportal/ioti-portal/vendor/assets/stylesheets
>    /Users/adrian/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/activeadmin->0ac35b7ff052/app/assets/images
>    /Users/adrian/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/activeadmin-??>0ac35b7ff052/app/assets/javascripts
>    /Users/adrian/.bundler/ruby/2.0.0/activeadmin->0ac35b7ff052/app/assets/stylesheets
>    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/jquery-ui-rails-5.0.5/app/assets/images
>    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/jquery-ui-rails->5.0.5/app/assets/javascripts
>    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/jquery-ui-rails->5.0.5/app/assets/stylesheets
>    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/formtastic-3.1.4/app/assets/stylesheets
>    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bourbon-4.2.7/app/assets/stylesheets
>    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/devise-bootstrap-views->0.0.8/app/assets/stylesheets
>    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails->3.2.2/app/assets/fonts
>    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails->3.2.2/app/assets/javascripts
>    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails->3.2.2/app/assets/stylesheets
>    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails->3.2.2/vendor/assets/stylesheets
>    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/jquery-rails->4.1.1/vendor/assets/javascripts
>    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/coffee-rails-4.1.1/lib/assets/javascripts
>
> Extracted source (around line #1):

```
@import "codelation";
@import "blog/variables";
@import "blog/**/*";
```

I feel like that probably has something to do with the fact that Blogelator didn't finish installing fully, but if that's a separate issue I'd be happy to try any fixes. I tried looking it up but must of what I found was specific to bootstrap.

However, I'm mainly looking for help in how to get Blogelator to install when there's a rake command that stops the install. Thanks!